# A simple “what am I?” riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> I offer glimpses of the future,
>
> communication with the past.
>
> Often optimistic,
>
> rarely pessimistic,
>
> yet an important piece of both.

What am I?

Comment: "This question may invite speculative answers" - Is that not the idea of this?

Comment: There are indeed speculative answers, none of which is really satisfying, but it might very well be that the correct answer is indisputably so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe

> A Mystic

I offer glimpses of the future

> A Mystic will tell you your future

communication with the past

> A Mystic might perform a seance

Often optimistic / rarely pessimistic

> Because you are paying them, they'll often tell you what you want to hear

yet an important piece of both

> Mistic = Mystic? It's a stretch...

Comment: This was what I was going for, good job!

Answer (score 3):

You are

> The weather report

I offer glimpses of the future

> That's what the weather forecast is about.

communication with the past

> One can find weather reports from years ago.

Often optimistic, rarely pessimistic

> Presentators tend to be.

yet an important piece of both

> "mist" is a piece of both words.

Answer (score 2):

> You are a **Psychic**

I offer glimpses of the future,

> Clairvoyance means you can see the future

communication with the past.

> A medium to communicate with the deceased

Often optimistic,

> Often tell you what you want to hear

rarely pessimistic,

> This may be bad for business

yet an important piece of both.

> **Mystic**al forces at play.

Comment: This is basically the answer I had in mind. Good job

Answer (score 1):

My take is :

> Dreams

I offer glimpses of the future,

> We dream of becoming something (in our thoughts) in future and as a result we sometime see a glimpse of the same happening in our dreams.

communication with the past.

> We can see past events as well in our dreams.

Often optimistic,

rarely pessimistic,

> We often have a positive approach towards our dreams and rarely think negative about them.

yet an important piece of both.

> Yet dreams comprises of both good dreams as well as bad dreams and past and future as well.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is :

> A time machine or a device which can help us see through time.

I offer glimpses of the future,

> Though **fictitious**, a time machine helps a person to see future.

communication with the past

> A person can travel or see past as well using time machine.

Often optimistic,

rarely pessimistic,

> In movies and other series a time manipulating or travel devices are seen in an optimistic approach and rarely in pessimistic manner.

yet an important piece of both.

> It is important for both past and future.

Answer (score 1):

You are:

> Necromancy

I offer glimpses of the future

> Necromancy is often used to gain insight into future events using spirits who would foretell coming events.

communication with the past

> Necromancy literally involves summoning and communicating with the spirit of the deceased (i.e the past)

Often optimistic,rarely pessimistic

> This is slightly harder to make sense with, as I'm not sure if necromancy is characterized by optimistic or pessimistic insights.

yet an important piece of both

> I suppose there might be instances where optimism and pessimism is combined, that in order for the person summoning the spirit to achieve a positive future he has to overcome some obstacles or whatnot

Answer (score 0):

Answer may be:

> Innovative Technology

I offer glimpses of the future,

> New technology can give glimpse of future.

communication with the past.

> We develop new technology from the work of past generation.

Often optimistic,

> New technology like mobile, TV, plane is often seen optimistically.

rarely pessimistic,

> Invention of dynamite has some pessimistic views but this is rare.

yet an important piece of both.

> It is.